# Laravel full join with groupby and count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

i am trying to get master child in laravel , with count(child) and all master raw, with groupby. below is the table records and laravel code as well.

Parent table

```
    +-------------+------------+  
    | Id          | Name       |
    +-------------+------------+  
    | 1           | a          |
    +-------------+------------+    
    | 2           | b          |
    +-------------+------------+ 
    | 3           | c          |
    +-------------+------------+
```

Child table

```
    +-------------+------------+  
    | parent_Id   | Code       |
    +-------------+------------+
    | 1           | d1         |
    +-------------+------------+ 
    | 1           | d1         |
    +-------------+------------+    
    | 1           | d1         |
    +-------------+------------+ 
    | 1           | d1         |
    +-------------+------------+    
    | 2           | d2         |
    +-------------+------------+ 
    | 2           | d3         |
    +-------------+------------+
```

Result
count all same parent ids in child and display all master ids, if child dont have master id than 0.

```
    +-------------+----------------------+ 
    |countparentIds in child| parentName       
    +-------------+----------------------+ 
    | 6                     | a          |
    +-------------+----------------------+  
    | 2                     | b          |
    +-------------+----------------------+  
    | 0                     | c          |
    +-------------+----------------------+
```

Now my laravel eloquent is like below.

```
 $master = DB::table('parents')
        ->select(array('parent.name as Name', DB::raw('COUNT(child.parent_id) as countparentids')))
        ->join('child', 'parent.id', '=', 'child.parent_id', 'left outer')
        ->where(child.code,'d1')
        ->orderBy('parent.name')
        ->groupBy('parent.id')
        ->groupBy('parent.name')
        ->get();
```

Now i was get the result, parent table all rows, and count child which has parent id.

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: the result does not display all the parent rows, it does display the child count but not all the parent rows, i am looking for all parent name, countofchild_parentid.

Comment: for instanc child table has code = d1, so the result should be first row     countparentids in child = 4 , parentname = a                                                       countparentids in child = 0 , parentname = b                                                              countparentid in child = 0 , parentname = c

Comment: use leftJoin instead of join

Answer (score 0):

Try with **CASE WHEN**
Like this

```
   $ter = DB::table('parents')
    ->leftjoin('child', 'parent.id', '=', 'child.parent_id')
    ->select(array('parent.name as Name', DB::raw('CASE WHEN (child.code= "d1") THEN COUNT(child.parent_id) ELSE 0 END as countparentids')))
    ->orderBy('parent.name')
    ->groupBy('parent.name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: my code is leftjoin join('table' ,'parent.column' ,'=',' 'childcol', 'left outer').

Comment: Okay that's correct you need to give your where condition on case basis

Comment: What do u mean by case basis.

Comment: As you writing the `->where(child.code,'d1')` so you are not getting desired o/p

Comment: Just try this and check you are getting your o/p or not

Comment: Not working . case when displays master all rows but now it does not count the child rows where child.code = d1 and parentid = child.id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150715/discussion-between-muhabutti-and-bibhudatta-sahoo).